# Is there any legal procedure to go through when a movie makes reference to real world coporations?

Tags: legal, m3gan

In the movie, M3gan, they made a direct reference to Apple app store and Google play store at the bottom right corner of the screenshot.

Can they do this?

The reason I am asking is: when it comes to a real world reference, a movie normally changes it a bit, e.g. CNN is changed to BNN, ISIS is changed to ICO etc.

This is the first time I see real world reference in a movie. Wondering if there is legal procedure to go through in order to make it work.

[image: m3gan]

Comment: Couldn't that be a kind of [product placement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_placement) (real or in disguise)?

Comment: As another comment said, it seems like product placement. We had similar questions [Apple products in movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/48984/apple-products-in-movies), [Why does Arrow have so much Microsoft product placement?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/31003/why-does-arrow-have-so-much-microsoft-product-placement) etc

Comment: See also: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85139/did-spaceballs-have-to-get-permission-for-pizza-the-hutt Short version: it’s unlikely there’s anything preventing a movie or TV show from referencing real world companies as long as they don’t seriously damage the brand. That said, as others have mentioned, it’s always an opportunity for product placement. I am not a lawyer. You might ask about using trademarks in creative works on https://law.stackexchange.com.